# Microsoft Bluetooth Stack into Widcomm Bluetooth Stack?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, bluetooth, broadcom

I have the following problem:
I implemented a managed mobile application for Windows Mobile devices using the C# Bluetooth library of InTheHand. 
Now I figured out that the new devices of HTC will all have the Widcomm Bluetooth stack instead of the Microsoft Bluetooth stack...
Does anybody know some working C# library for the Widcomm Bluetooth stack? And also how limited the widcomm api is, concerning e.g. being able to turn bluetooth on/off or having an Obex listener? 
Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the disclaimer, I'm the maintainer of the 32feet.NET library. :-)

Version 2.4 of 32feet.NET from InTheHand includes Widcomm/Broadcom support.  Have you tried that?  I get the feeling you might have...

To run ObexListener firstly we'd need a way to disable Widcomm's built-in OBEX server (if that can be done I can make the changes necessary to have ObexListener run).  There might be support for enabling/disabling the radio on CE/WM -- I think that API is missing on Win32 however.

The other options with ObexListener are to run it on a personal Service Class Id, as long as the client app knows that it will work.  Or perhaps you could use the Widcomm API directly, which might allow you to intercept the PUT objects you need...

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! I will try to use the Widcomm API directly in order to get hold of the objects somehow. I'll keep you updated or post in the 32feet forum how my results turn out!

Comment: Oh and by the way, yes I tried out the InTheHand library and I actually got the obex listener running but it doesn't block in the moment when he should "listen" for some context, it just continues...